# can I have annual subscription and top up features in one mobile app

Tags: android, blackberry, in-app-purchase, itunes, in-app-billing

I want to make a mobile app where users need to purchase licence every year to continue using it. Once they buy it from the app store/market they will get a one year subscription plus 10 POINTS credit which they need for a specific part of the app. Whenever they want to use that specific part of the app, they must have enough points. Otherwise, they may top up.

Is that possible in iTunes, Google Play and BlackBerry App World? I mean can I have annual subscription and top up features in one app.

And, can the unused points be carried over next subscription? In case the licence is over but not the credits!

Comment: Maybe you can do it using some kind of external service (developed by yourself) to authenticate people onto your app before they use it. In this way, you should assure dates, type of suscription, etc.

Comment: but, can users purchase credit directly from the app store/market? We don't want to handle the payment ourselves!

Comment: I dont know, but as far as I know, when I purchase an app I only pay once (and forever). So I think that you need that kind of service developed and supported by yourself.

Comment: This is a separate question for each platform.  It is overly broad as asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need both subscription and one-off purchase revenue models. The subscription model is fairly simple to implement, and can be implemented without adding much code to your app. Your users will be charged a regular (monthly/yearly) fee to use your app.

The points/credits model will require you to keep track of the user's points balance inside your app. You can set up virtual goods on the various stores which the user can purchase in order to get more points e.g.

```
10 points - $0.99
30 points - $1.99
```

You may also need to think about how users can transfer their balance to a new phone if they change devices. (Note: This is mandatory on the BlackBerry platform, can't advise on the others).

Both of these revenue models are supported on the BlackBerry, Android and iOS platforms. Docs here: [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/in-app-purchase/index.html), [Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/index.html), [BlackBerry](https://developer.blackberry.com/appworld/payment/).